# How to catch signals from a unknown USB OTG device?

Tags: java, android, usb-otg

I have a USB OTG device which acts like a mouse, bought in china with not much more information about the used controller. When I connect it to my android there is a mouse cursor and the device has 5 hard buttons (left, right, up, down, enter). I want to programm the buttons for my app to performe specific tasks. So I need to read the input signals and overwrite them.

How can I catch the signals?

I found out the vendor (0x04D9) and product id (0x2519) and the controller name *Lenovo Calliope USB Keyboard*. But no idea about the used chip, it's covert.

It doesn't work with the methods `onKeyDown` or `dispatchKeyEvent`. Also not with `USB serial Lib` because the device is not found/ recognized with the provided VID und PID (see discussion with Fatih Şennik below, other devices are recognized with it).

My current assumption is that it is a Hardware/ Chip issue that I cannot get the signals. But the strange thing is that the device otherwise does what it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution if nothings works: I got an arduino controller and solder it to the buttons. It's not that complicated.

Important is that the controller supports hid e.g. the leonardo pro micro with the atmega32u4 chip. The code for the controller can be found easily with google.

Then it works with override onKeyDown or onKeyUp etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a USB serial Lib such as https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android and give vendor and product ID of your USB OTG device to control it. So you can catch left, right, up, down and hex codes in any monitor and based on the raw byte, you can do a switch like operation.

```
UsbSerialInterface.UsbReadCallback mCallback = new UsbSerialInterface.UsbReadCallback() { 
     //Defining a Callback which triggers whenever data is read.
        @Override
        public void onReceivedData(byte[] arg0) {
            String data = null;
            try {
                data = new String(arg0, "UTF-8");
                data.concat("/n");
                switch() // etc
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
```

Lets first try this to connect our android phone to the USB otg device. As for the product and vendor ids, you can find it when you plug it to your pc. if the connection is established then the rest will come. it would be helpful if you can share the USB Otg device data sheets here.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
        ProbeTable customTable = new ProbeTable();
        customTable.addProduct(0x0403, 0x6001, CdcAcmSerialDriver.class);

        List<UsbSerialDriver> availableDrivers = new UsbSerialProber(customTable).findAllDrivers(manager);
        ArrayAdapter<String> deviceList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2);
        ListView listDevices = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        if(!availableDrivers.isEmpty()) {
            for(UsbSerialDriver driver: availableDrivers) {
                deviceList.add(driver.getDevice().getDeviceName());
            }
            listDevices.setAdapter(deviceList);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No devices found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

if it is USB hid device, Trying this code might help;

```
UsbManager mManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = mManager.getDeviceList();
Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();

while (deviceIterator.hasNext())
    {
        UsbDevice device = deviceIterator.next();
        Log.i(TAG,"Model: " + device.getDeviceName());
        Log.i(TAG,"ID: " + device.getDeviceId());
        Log.i(TAG,"Class: " + device.getDeviceClass());
        Log.i(TAG,"Protocol: " + device.getDeviceProtocol());
        Log.i(TAG,"Vendor ID " + device.getVendorId());
        Log.i(TAG,"Product ID: " + device.getProductId());
        Log.i(TAG,"Interface count: " + device.getInterfaceCount());
        Log.i(TAG,"---------------------------------------");
   // Get interface details
        for (int index = 0; index < device.getInterfaceCount(); index++)
        {
        UsbInterface mUsbInterface = device.getInterface(index);
        Log.i(TAG,"  *****     *****");
        Log.i(TAG,"  Interface index: " + index);
        Log.i(TAG,"  Interface ID: " + mUsbInterface.getId());
        Log.i(TAG,"  Inteface class: " + mUsbInterface.getInterfaceClass());
        Log.i(TAG,"  Interface protocol: " + mUsbInterface.getInterfaceProtocol());
        Log.i(TAG,"  Endpoint count: " + mUsbInterface.getEndpointCount());
    // Get endpoint details 
            for (int epi = 0; epi < mUsbInterface.getEndpointCount(); epi++)
        {
            UsbEndpoint mEndpoint = mUsbInterface.getEndpoint(epi);
            Log.i(TAG,"    ++++   ++++   ++++");
            Log.i(TAG,"    Endpoint index: " + epi);
            Log.i(TAG,"    Attributes: " + mEndpoint.getAttributes());
            Log.i(TAG,"    Direction: " + mEndpoint.getDirection());
            Log.i(TAG,"    Number: " + mEndpoint.getEndpointNumber());
            Log.i(TAG,"    Interval: " + mEndpoint.getInterval());
            Log.i(TAG,"    Packet size: " + mEndpoint.getMaxPacketSize());
            Log.i(TAG,"    Type: " + mEndpoint.getType());
        }
        }
    }
    Log.i(TAG," No more devices connected.");
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! Can you provide a bit more context? I implement the lib but I cannot override the onReceivedData..

Comment: nice. it's a device i bought in china so that's my problem, I have not much information about the used controller. but with your help I found out that they use a 'Lenovo Calliope USB Keyboard' Controller with HID\VID_04D9&PID_2519&REV_0001&MI_00 for the keyboard and MI_01&Col01 for the mouse. so i think my vendor id is 0x04D9 and my product id is 0x2519? when I insert this, I still get the toast with no device found...

Comment: It's strange. the device and buttons are working fine if it's connected but I get no device information with your code and my ids. I double checked it, I used an app which read the vendor and product ids out of the connected device. Still nothing detected. So I tried another mouse from logitech and it works. I got the ids and with your code I got the device name... I guess it's a hardware problem?!

Comment: Hımm yes it might be related to Chinese mouse's USB to serial converter chip they might be using something apart from those chips that are supported by the app FTDI FT232R, FT232H, FT2232H, FT4232H, FT230X, FT231X, FT234XD, Prolific PL2303, Silabs CP2102, CP2105, Qinheng CH340, and CH341A. if you find which USB-serial chip they are using. you can download their driver and update the GitHub repo or send a pull request.

Comment: thanks for your effort. I disassembled it, the chip is covert and I cannot remove it without breaking the board. The only informations on the board are LKT-418 20190630. The last one is probably the production date and the first part ist some internal number but with no useful google result... I will stay on it a little longer but eventually i have to solder my own controller to the buttons.

Comment: keyboards typically implement an USB HID device and not a CDC device. Such HID devices do not show up in the USB device list as they are already handled by the Android OS.

Comment: @FatihŞennik does not work either... but I bought a arduino leonard atmega32u4, works on the first try. so I will rebuild the device...

Comment: @FatihŞennik your answer was the best I got, the bounty is yours.